# References on load time *.csv import TBs from GCS into BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Are they any references how long it takes to import 1TB, 10TB o csv files (not a single file; many that have in total 1TB, 10 TB)
from a GCS bucket to BigQuery via bg into a non-partitioned and a partitioned table?

Will BigQuery automatically scale during import e.g. importing many *.csv files from one bucket having in total 1GB needs 30 seconds.
Does it mean 100GB needs 100 * 30 seconds. Most likely it will be much faster, because of auto-scaling?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Service throttling in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47201781/service-throttling-in-bigquery)

Comment: You'll never get consistent times (see linked/duplicate question), and it's not linear either. Speaking from experience however, it's fast. The best way to know is simply try it out and see for yourself :)

Comment: Thank you! That helps a lot!